# corrplot margins in RStudio are too small

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, r-corrplot

When I produce a graphic in R-Studio, the margins are too small that it cuts off the graphic in the plot area. The output below follows [this tutorial](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/chi-square-test-of-independence-in-r), which uses the `corrplot` library to run Pearson Chi-square residuals. No matter how I adjust my plot area or zoom or export, the bottom is still cut off. How do I adjust this?

[image: plot area]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the image displayed just fine. Maybe you can try playing around with the margins - `mar` parameter that is also internal to `corrplot()`

Here is what I get with some margins:

```
corrplot(chisq$residuals, is.cor=FALSE, mar=c(5,2,2,1))
```

[image: margins]

You can also try transposing the matrix so it becomes extended horizontally, but not sure if that fits your needs:

```
corrplot(t(chisq$residuals), is.cor=FALSE, mar=c(5,2,2,1))
```

[image: horiz]

Comment: Hi, and thank you for answering the question. I think in your first image you can see that the bottom figure (7.53) is cut off, so that's what I was trying to avoid. The `mar()` parameter helped and the transpose `t()` parameter was also really cool. Still, I can't seem to get it to look right in R-Studio. When I try it in R, it works okay though.